# "Preventing downtime and faults IS/ARE crucial"

Tags: grammatical-number

Consider the following sentence:

> Preventing downtime and faults is crucial.

Is or are? Why?

Comment: The subject is the noun phrase *preventing downtime and faults*. If you had to pick a one-word subject, it would be *preventing*, which is singular.

Comment: If you rearrange your words (downtime and faults prevention is crucial), it can make it easier to decide on a verb's number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Preventing downtime and faults is crucial.*

As usual, this sentence has been extensively reduced; this always produces ambiguities.
With all the bells and whistles in place again, we see that the source can be 
**either**

- *[Preventing downtime is crucial] and [preventing faults is crucial].

  **or***
- *Preventing [downtime and  faults] is crucial.*

depending on whether preventing one is considered separate from preventing the other, and both are considered crucial (the first variant), or whether downtime and faults are considered related phenomena, and preventing both together is considered crucial (the second variant).

In the first case you use *are*, because there are two separate phenomena, and
in the second case you use *is*, because there is only one phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

> Preventing downtime and faults is crucial.

Simple rewording. What is crucial to prevent?

> **It** is crucial to prevent downtime and faults.

But

> Downtimes and faults are crucial to prevent.

And

> Downtime and fault are crucial to prevent.

Does not work.

But

> Downtime and fault are both things we don't like that are crucial to prevent.
>   I think faults needs to be in plural. The singular looks weird.

And

> Downtime and faults (both) are crucial to prevent.

Comment: Your replacement with **It** does not clarify, imo. Take *They are coming.* *Who is it that you say are coming?* *It is they.* *Who is "they"?* etc...

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is simply *is*.

The subject of your sentence is the word *preventing*, which is singular, as would be singing, blowing, cringing, believing, rowing, trying, helping, understanding, jumping, punching, loving, kissing, struggling, ad infinitum.

I prefer keeping the sentence as is, by the way. Having the word *it* as the first word of the sentence in unnecessary. Further, with *it* as the first word, it's hard to tell what its referent of *it*, is; that is, what is *it*, to what does *it* refer? Beats me!

I've noticed the it "habit" can be unlearned with a little inventive word play, as can many other habits, such as the

> Due to the fact that . . .

habit, by simply changing it to one word:

> Because . . .